# Vue component works as expected only after Hot Reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, datatable

Googled for hours but couldn't find solution(plus explanation as well).

I have Vue select component related with Datatable:

```
        <select @change="statusChanged()" v-model="active" name="FilterStatus" id="FilterStatus" class="form-control selectp"  data-placeholder="FilterStatus" tabindex="2">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option :value="true">Active</option>
          <option :value="false">Inactive</option>
        </select>
```

With on-change function "statusChanged":

```
data() {
  return {
    active: 'all'
  }
},
methods: {
    ...
    statusChanged(){
        if (this.active === true) {
          $("#CustomerTable")
            .DataTable()
            .columns( 1 )
            .search( true )
            .draw();
        } else if (this.active === false) {
         ....
    }
  },
```

My purpose is just to change the status by selecting at dropdown element. The main PROBLEM is that it is working only AFTER hot reload and not just on refresh of page! For example:

step 1: I load page for first time
step 2: Dropdown is not working and value "active" is not changing
step 3: I change the code in my editor(no matter what), save it -> hot reload is triggering and after select options work and Datatable is refreshing with filters applied!

Why so? Any ideas or suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a new vue project and worked correctly, maybe you have an error that causes your variable active not work (Check the browser console)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <select @change="statusChanged()" v-model="active" name="FilterStatus" id="FilterStatus" class="form-control selectp"  data-placeholder="FilterStatus" tabindex="2">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option :value="true">Active</option>
      <option :value="false">Inactive</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      active: 'all'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    statusChanged(){
        console.log(this.active);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am sure your code is working. But I am curious why my code work ONLY after Hot realod?

Comment: I need more info about your code for can help you, Maybe you can shared the complete component and vue/node versions

Comment: I have js error in console saygin "Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_FilterStatus". 

- Vue.js version - 2.6.11 
- Vue2-datepicker: 2.13.4

Comment: Then, your mistake is not for active variable or method statusChanged because dont see "Select2 s2id_FilterStatus" in your vue component. Can you edit your question and add the vue component that is failing?

Comment: It's the same component. Id and name of select tag is "FilterStatus". If I delete the code above with select element the error dissapears

Comment: I know that is same component but in your post you can copy&paste all your component without the dots '....' because i need see all code from your component, specially the tags: <template> and <script>